# Kivy display image at full resolution

Tags: kivy

I am using Kivy 1.9 and Python 3.4.

I have an image that is 5400x2700. I have a screen with 1920x1200 resolution.

How can I display the image at its full/native resolution and add scroll features to my main window to view areas of the image not initially displayed?

I have tried to use `allow_stretch=True` and `keep_ratio=False` to display the image at its native, but the picture still condenses to fit on my monitor. Additionally, I have tried to set the `size=(5400, 2700)` for the `Image`, but the it still fits inside my existing window.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't actually set the image size; if its parent is a layout, your manual setting is ignored. Try seting its size and also set its size_hint to `None, None`.

Comment: yeah, almost about the same time you posted that I realized it myself and was about to update my post. However, figured I should just accept your answers. All I did after that was to add the image widget to a scatter widget and disable scaling for my desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: A ScrollView is probably better than a Scatter if you just want scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `allow_stretch = False`, `keep_ratio = True`, to allow the image to resize to its original size